# Filter the values of 15 columns by 3 SD with 100+ rows

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

I have a dataset with 15 columns col1 to col15 being numeric. I have 100 rows of data with names attached to each row as a factor. I want to do a summary for each row for all 15 columns.

```
 head(df2phcl[,c(1:16)])
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15             NAME
78   95  101  100   84   93   93   85   81    97    80    94    81    79   87         R04-001 
100   61   96   75   98   92   99   99  102    83    84    NA   101    93    96         R04-002 
81   84   82   83   77   86   90   92   92    78    86    91    59    80    84         R04-003 
91   84   87   95  103   93   92   95   86    92   107    96    94    87    97         R04-004 
72   79   66   98   84   75   85   83   75    80    91    65    90    81    73         R04-005 
72   75   68   44   79   64   83   71   81    82    85    63    87    94    60         R04-006
```

My code for this is.

```
library(dplyr)
####Rachis
SUMCL <- df2phcl %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
summarise(CL = mean(c(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15), na.rm=T),
        CLMAX = max(c(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15), na.rm=T),
        CLMIN = min(c(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15), na.rm=T),
        CLSTD = sd(c(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15), na.rm=T),
        OUT = outliers(c(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15), na.rm=T))
head(SUMCL)
tail(SUMCL)
```

My resulting analysis comes out as...

```
Error: 
  Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

I've also tried this...

```
df2phcl$col1+col2+col3+col4+col5+col6+col7+col8+col9+col10+col11+col12+col13+co114+col15[!df2phcl$col1+col2+col3+col4+col5+col6+col7+col8+col9+col10+col11+col12+col13+col14+col15%in%boxplot.stats(df2phcl$col1+col2+col3+col4+col5+col6+col7+col8+col9+col10+co111+col12+col13+col14+col15)$out]

This returns ....
   Error: object 'col2' not found
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong this works with mean, max, min, and sd.

```
> head(SUMCL)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
# Groups:   ENTRY, NAME, HEADCODE, RHTGENES, HEAD, PL [6]
  ENTRY             NAME HEADCODE RHTGENES   HEAD    PL    PH       CL CLMAX CLMIN     CLSTD
  <int>           <fctr>   <fctr>   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1         R04-001       CAW     Rht1   Club   319    83 88.53333   101    78  7.989875
2     2         R04-002       LBW Wildtype Common   330   102 91.35714   102    61 11.770936
3     3         R04-003       CBW     Rht2   Club   230    82 83.00000    92    59  8.220184
4     4         R04-004       LBW     Rht1 Common   328   117 93.26667   107    84  6.192930
5     5         R04-005       CBW     Rht1   Club   280    97 79.80000    98    65  9.182281
6     6         R04-006       LAW     Rht1 Common   310    92 73.86667    94    44 12.749603
```

I'm just wanting to filter the outliers at 3 sd or more and then use the dplyr to package to do my statistics...

Comment: What code did you run to produce `SUMCL`? Also, what is it you want to filter? Do you want to set values that are greater than 3SD from the mean (for their row) to `NA`?

Comment: I changed the code to SUMCL. I wanted to filter out anything that was above 3 SD above and below the mean. Yes, I think setting them to NA would be okay too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so let me know if the code below is on the right track.

The approach below is to convert the data from wide to long format, which makes it much easier to do the summaries for each level of `name`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = as.data.frame(replicate(15, rnorm(100)))
names(dat) = paste0("col", 1:15)
dat$name = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=10), rep(letters[1:10], 10))

# Convert data to long format, remove outliers and summarize
dat %>% 
  gather(column, value, -name) %>%  # reshape from wide to long
  group_by(name) %>%                # summarize by name
  mutate(value = replace(value, abs(value - mean(value)) > 2*sd(value), NA)) %>%  # set outliers to NA
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
            max = max(value, na.rm=TRUE),
            sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE))
```

> ```
>     name         mean      max        sd
>  1    Aa  0.007848188 1.238744 0.8510016
>  2    Ab -0.208536464 1.980401 1.2764606
>  3    Ac -0.152986713 1.587845 0.8443106
>  4    Ad -0.413543054 0.965692 0.7225872
>  5    Ae -0.112648322 1.178716 0.7269527
>  6    Af  0.442268890 2.048040 1.0350119
>  7    Ag  0.390627994 1.978260 0.8716681
>  8    Ah  0.080505879 2.396349 1.3128403
>  9    Ai  0.257925059 1.984474 1.0196722
> 10    Aj  0.137469703 1.470177 0.7192616
> # ... with 90 more rows
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get some of the col std. dev. changed; however, I'm not sure how many observations it took out. I was wanting to take out from the top and the bottom of the distribution at an even amount. Like a trimmed mean, it would take out 20% of the obs. from the top and bottom of the distribution. What I was curious about was just leaving the observations from the top and bottom (+-3 SD) of the distribution.

```
> SUMCL <- df2phcl %>% 
+   gather(column, value, -c(ENTRY, NAME, HEADCODE, RHTGENES, HEAD,PL,PH)) %>%  # reshape from wide to long
+   group_by(ENTRY, NAME, HEADCODE, RHTGENES, HEAD,PL,PH) %>%                # summarize by name
+   mutate(value = replace(value, abs(value - mean(value)) > 2*sd(value), NA)) %>%  # set outliers to NA
+   summarise(CL = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
+             CLMAX = max(value, na.rm=TRUE),
+             CLMIN = min(value, na.rm=TRUE),
+             N = sum(!is.na(value), na.rm=TRUE),
+             CLSTD= sd(value, na.rm=TRUE),
+             CLSE = (CLSTD / sqrt(N)))
> head(SUMCL)
# A tibble: 6 x 13
# Groups:   ENTRY, NAME, HEADCODE, RHTGENES, HEAD, PL [6]
  ENTRY             NAME HEADCODE RHTGENES   HEAD    PL    PH       CL CLMAX CLMIN     N     CLSTD     CLSE
  <int>           <fctr>   <fctr>   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1         R04-001       CAW     Rht1   Club   319    83 88.53333   101    78    15  7.989875 2.062977
2     2         R04-002       LBW Wildtype Common   330   102 91.35714   102    61    14 11.770936 3.145915
3     3         R04-003       CBW     Rht2   Club   230    82 84.71429    92    77    14  5.029583 1.344213
4     4         R04-004       LBW     Rht1 Common   328   117 92.28571   103    84    14  5.075258 1.356420
5     5         R04-005       CBW     Rht1   Club   280    97 79.80000    98    65    15  9.182281 2.370855
6     6         R04-006       LAW     Rht1 Common   310    92 76.00000    94    60    14 10.076629 2.693093
```